# How to set the startup location of Linux terminal in R different from Rproj location

Tags: r, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I start up R-Studio the terminal's working directory is set to wherever the R-Project is located. However, I want to keep the R-Project on the drive where Windows is located and the terminal to be set to a specific folder on WSL2. Is that possible?

My R as well as my R-Studio are installed on Windows, because the installation on WSL2 itself were not working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio, if you navigate in the Files tab to the directory of interest, you can immediately select "Open New Terminal Here" which you will find under the "More" tab.

Tools->Terminal->Terminal Options lets you select from three options [Project Directory, Current Directory and Home Directory] for the Initial Directory where terminal loads which might also be of interest to you.